# Hey I am trying to get 12.0 as answer but getting 12 how can i turn this number into a float,

Tags: javascript

As you can see I am trying to getting 12.0. But instead i am getting 12 how can i add a 0 and make this number to a float please help

****JavaScript***

```
 let a = 6.0;
    let b = 6.0;
    console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .toFixed()

```js
const a = 6;
const b = 6;

console.log ( (a+b).toFixed(1) );
```

Comment: thank you very much brother...

Comment: @sam_desksepoil https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Glad I could help @sam_desksepoil don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)